# How do executables connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, exe

We have an `.exe` file that connects to a SQL Server database, and generates a record file (`.txt`) based on a specific table. Is there a specific connection or port that `.exe` files use to connect to SQL Server?

I did not create the `.exe` so I do not know the EXACT operations, but I do know what the file should do, and is not. The file generates a log that shows:

> Failed while executing: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

There is nothing in the SQL Server logs in regards to this, which I suppose I would expect since it seems the `.exe` file is not getting there.

All features of the server are running as it should ie SSIS packages, log-in...etc, and if I manually execute the action ran by the .exe I have no issues with the desired output.

Comment: Usually they connect using standard libraries that accept a `connection string` to know which server to connect to, and special ports, etc. Hopefully, there's some kind of file kept next to the `exe` that stores the connection string in clear text. E.g. if it was a .NET application, we'd expect to find the connection string in a file with a `.config` extension.

Comment: The error basically means that the client cannot connect at all. It could be it's using a wrong server name, the server being down, or a firewall blocking the connection. In any case, the client is not even made to the server, which is consistent with your observation of no logs at all.

Comment: Need to see the connection string - is it using a hardcoded IP address instead of DNS name?

Comment: It would seem there is no accompanying config file with the .exe, any other way to view the connection string its using?

Comment: Unless the server name is hard-coded in the exec, it is externally configured. ".config" files are commonly used for .NET apps but unmanaged apps may use ".ini" files or the registry. Has it ever worked? Maybe the necessary config file is missing.

Comment: yeah the .exe file ran fine for quite sometime. We recently virtualized the server and I have had to run those operations manually since...which isn't time consuming, but it would be nice to get it automated again. no accompanying .ini file either. I am wondering if the server name is hard coded into the .exe file then....we did rename the server to Server_NameV (for virtual). I suppose this would be off topic for this board, but is there a way to view the contents of the .exe?

Comment: Open the file in a hex editor and search for the name of the server

Comment: never used a hex editor before. would HexEd.it work for that purpose?

Comment: I don't see why not, all depends on size of your exe and if you're comfortable using an online editor!

Comment: yeah that's a good point. I found a few offline options. I will update with how it turns out. Thanks

Comment: If it's a .Net app then there are quite a few free decompilers around such as dnSpy or dotPeek

Answer (score 1):

> we did rename the server to Server_NameV (for virtual)

On the client, create an [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/create-or-delete-a-server-alias-for-use-by-a-client?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=%20To%20create%20an%20alias%20%201%20In,named%20instance%20append%20the%20instance%20name.%20More%20) that redirects the *old* name to the *new* server.

[image]

Or the application could be hard-coded to use an [ODBC DSN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/what-is-a-dsn-data-source-name-ae9a0c76-22fc-8a30-606e-2436fe26e89f) which you could edit to point to the new server.